# A question about framedragging

Tags: general-relativity, frame-dragging

Is the spacetime curvature caused by gravito-magnetism constant, or does it change over time, like winding up a spring? I mean, if a heavy spinning mass, for example a neutron star (or the earth, for which the effect has been proven with very sensitive equipment like the gravity B probe), causes the "surrounding" space to warp with the rotation, will space be dragged more and more over time or is the deformation caused by the spinning mass constant.
In other words, is there a difference in the curvature for an earth that spins 1000 000 years compare to one that spins for 1000 000 000 years?

To clarify, is the frame dragged a certain amount independent of time, or is it dragged a certain amount per unit time?

Comment: Give more details... spacetime curveture is determined by the stress-energy tensor on the GR.

Answer (score 2):

Lets look at a spherical symmetric mass, spinning with a constant angular velocity $\Omega$ around a rotation axis, which I will identify as the ($\theta=0$)-axis in canonical spherical coordinates. The line element outside this mass is given by $$ds^2=-e^\nu dt^2+e^\lambda dr^2+r^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta(d\phi-\omega dt)^2)+O(\Omega^2).$$
This is the first order (in $\Omega$) Hartle-Thorne line element of a slow spinning spherical mass. $\nu$, $\lambda$ and $\omega$ are functions of $r$ only. $\nu$ and $\lambda$ are of order $O(\Omega^0)$: they are related to the mass as rest and come from the TOV-equation. $\omega$ is of order $O(\Omega^1)$. $\omega$ is the frame-dragging frequency and it is the metric potential of the off diagonal metric component $g_{\phi t}$. Outside the mass it is given by $$\omega=\frac{2J}{r^3},$$ where J is the total angular momentum of the star and in order $O(\Omega^1)$ is is given by $$J=I(M,\nu)\Omega.$$ $I$ is the relativistic equivalent to the classical moment of inertia.

So now what does that mean? First, the frame dragging frequency is not equal to the masses rotation frequency: the free-falling reference frame and the co rotating frame have different angular velocities. Second, the frame dragging frequency is (in first order in $\Omega$) proportional to the masses rotation frequency. So if the mass stays in static rotation and keeps its shape and mass the frame dragging frequency will stay constant over time. If the mass or the rotation frequency change the frame dragging frequency will change because $I$ or $\Omega$ change.

So for the earth the slow rotation approximation is certainly valid but earth is not spherical. But lets say it is, then one could use the metric above if one assumes that $\Omega$ is constant or changes very slow. $\Omega$ actually does decrease very slow due to for example tide friction. So if lets say earth rotation frequency decreases by 1% in 1 million years (which I picked out here without checking how much is actually would be) but its mass stays constant and is assumed to be spherical, then the frame dragging frequency would decrease by 1% as well.

Comment: So the spinning mass induced change in curvature will "wind up" in the course of time?

Comment: What do you mean with "wind up"? If the rotation frequency of the earth decreases the frame dragging frequency will decrease by the same amount. For a given point in time the frame dragging frequency is considered as constant on a shell of constant radius around earth here in my discussion.